# Add Javascript by URL Alias

Tags: javascript, path-aliases

I've been using this code from drupal.org to add javascript to a page node.

```
    function example_preprocess_html(&$variables){
       if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 585) {
         drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') . '/js/accform.js');
       }
    }
```

What I want to do is add the javascript based on page and sub pages with it.

Example: www.example/about and www.example.com.about/directions

Is a way to do this in the existing code?

https://www.drupal.org/node/304178

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/196392) and you should be able to adjust the code accordingly